# Mvc ViewBag - Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to set a bool to true in the controller when producing a certain view and then alter the header of the view accordingly. This should be dead simple but instead Im getting:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform
>   runtime binding on a null reference

All I'm doing is in controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.IsRegistration = true;
    return View();
}
```

and then in view:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsRegistration)
{
    <legend>Register using another service.</legend>
}
else
{
    <legend>Use another service to log in.</legend>
}
```

but it fails on:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsRegistration)
```

**UPDATE**

Relevant Controller Code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.IsRegistration = "true";
    return View();
}
```

The register view:

```
@model Mvc.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AccountLayout.cshtml";
     ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
            <legend>Create a new account.</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The ExternalLoginsList partial:

```
@using Glimpse.Core.Extensions
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security
@model ICollection<AuthenticationDescription>

@if (Model.Count == 0)
{
    <div class="message-info">
        <p>There are no external authentication services configured</p>
    </div>
}
else
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <fieldset id="socialLoginList">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.IsRegistration))
            {
            <legend>Register using another service.</legend>
            }
            else
            {
            <legend>Use another service to log in.</legend>
            }
            <p>
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in Model) {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                }
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing but Maybe the viewbag can't handle handle boolean values?  have you tried `ViewBag.IsRegistration = "true";` and checking the string for `ViewBag.IsRegistration == "true"` instead?

Comment: @AirL - That doesn't work. Its just the same thing isn't it?

Comment: No,  since anything can be sent to the view through the view bag the view doesn't know what type it is.  So often you have to cast the view bag as what is being sent.

Comment: @Trevor - no that doesn't work either. Error becomes Value cannot be null.Parameter name: value. Im clearly misunderstanding what the viewbag is.

Comment: Hmm it seems like the view bag is not actually being set.  If you try printing out the viewbag to html does it work.

Comment: Its not just the bool. Does anything on your ViewBag gets set at all? I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: ViewBag is not null but nothing seems to go in there. The properties in the intellisense are purple.. whatever that means. So intellisense "knows" about them but they are null at runtime.

Comment: @Trevor no I cant just print them. ViewBag is not null however. Obviously there is something I "dont know" which is preventing me from giving the right info for you guys to help me. It shouldn't be this hard should it.

Comment: @rism i believe your problem is that you are setting the `ViewBag.IsRegistration = "true";` in the `Register Action` and checking for it in `ExternalLoginPartial`. You need to set it in the action that is returning the `ExternalLoginPartial`.

Comment: @FloodGravemind Yep that turns out to be the case. I will drop an answer to that effect. tyvm

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsRegistration == true)
```

Comment: Easiest and the fastest solution.

Comment: don't forget to check for null

Comment: is it really required to check for null?

Comment: You don't have to check for null because `null == true` evaluates correctly to `false`. Without the `== true`, a null wouldn't be a valid value for the `@if` condition.

Comment: Interesting solution. 
the only downside I can see if another dev might not understand why this is there, and could think that removing the == true as a quick simplification to the code

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question, but I think I have an elegant answer, so in case anyone reads this after searching, here is mine:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsRegistration ?? false)
```

Comment: I only like this one a bit more than the "==true" option because it's a bit more obvious that you are doing a null check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Replace the line in your controller:

```
ViewBag.IsRegistration = true;
```

with

```
ViewBag.IsRegistration = new bool?(true);
```

and replace the line in your view:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsRegistration)
```

with

```
@if ((ViewBag.IsRegistration as bool?).Value)
```

Effectively you are putting a nullable bool in the ViewBag and then unwrapping it.

Comment: Thx but with that code I get Nullable object must have value error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for `null` before checking for `true`:

```
if (ViewBag.IsRegistration != null && ViewBag.IsRegistration)
```

Comment: That's what others have suggested but the problem is that it's always null. So doing the check prevents the error which is great but it's never true.

Comment: Wrong. If you set it, it will be true - bool. If you don't it will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so as per Floods suggestion in comments, I need to pass the arguments around. The ViewBag from the parent View does not flow through to partial views.

So in the code for the Register View I needed to change from

```
 <section id="socialLoginForm">
       @Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl})
 </section>
```

to

```
<section id="socialLoginForm">
    @Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList",
            new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl,
                 IsRegistering = @ViewBag.IsRegistering })
</section>
```

Then go into my account controller and change from:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginsList(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return (ActionResult)PartialView("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new List<AuthenticationDescription>(AuthenticationManager.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes()));
}
```

to

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginsList(string returnUrl, string isRegistering) {
   ViewBag.IsRegistering = (isRegistering.ToLower() == "true");
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return (ActionResult)PartialView("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new List<AuthenticationDescription>(AuthenticationManager.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes()));
}
```

Then in the ExternalLogins I can just:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsRegistering)
```

as necessary.

So Im effectively passing the IsRegistering bool from controller to main view then back up to action method on controller then into ViewBag which allow me to access the bool in the child partial view.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try TempData instead of ViewBag.

Change your code from

Controller

```
ViewBag.IsRegistration=true;
```

to

```
TempData["IsReg"]=true;
```

and in View

```
@if((bool)TempData["IsReg"])
```

It seems that you are using the value in child partial view and you are adding the data in parent action.The values in viewbag cannot pass out data from one action to anothers action's view. While TempData use session it can be used to pass data to one action to another actions view.

Answer (score 0):

Booleans in Viewbag are always tricky. Try this instead

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            ViewBag.Registration = "x";//x or whatever
            return View();
        }

@if (!String.IsNullorEmpty(ViewBag.Registration))
        {
        <legend>Register using another service.</legend>
        }
        else
        {
        <legend>Use another service to log in.</legend>
        }
```

Comment: That stops the error message but it never recognizes that IsRegistration=="true".

Comment: You just have to check if the string is null or empty `!String.IsNullorEmpty(ViewBag.Registration)`. If it is not null or empty that means it is true.

Comment: Yes that's what Im doing    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.IsRegistration)) but it never recognises that Ive set ViewBag.IsRegistration = "true" or any other string in the controller.

Comment: I just checked the code first check for Null or Empty string and then check for value of the string. I even checked it for Boolean are you sure you are setting the ViewBag.IsRegistration Property?

Comment: Ive just updated the post with some code. But yes Im sure Im setting it it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so:

```
@if ((ViewBag.IsRegistration != null) && (ViewBag.IsRegistration is bool) && (bool)ViewBag.IsRegistration)
{
}
```