# ViewBag return difference between input and label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In Controller

```
    public IActionResult List()
    {
        ViewBag.SomeThingERR = true;// something bool value
        return View();
    }
```

In view

```
<input type="text" id="SomeThingERR2" value="@ViewBag.SomeThingERR" />
<label>SomeThingERR:</label>  @ViewBag.SomeThingERR
```

Result

input = value

lable = True?

I don't know why it difference value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everything rendered in the view is text, try to convert non-string entities into a string explicitly.

```
<input type="text" id="SomeThingERR2" value="@(ViewBag.SomeThingERR.ToString())" />
<label>SomeThingERR:</label>  @(ViewBag.SomeThingERR.ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the contents of the ViewBag, you can do so.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.SomeThingERR ="true";// something bool value
            return View();
           
        }
```

View：

```
<input type="text" id="SomeThingERR2" value=@ViewBag.SomeThingERR />
<label>SomeThingERR:</label>  @ViewBag.SomeThi
```

If you have a logical judgment, you can refer to this article:[Mvc ViewBag - Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553466/mvc-viewbag-cannot-convert-null-to-bool-because-it-is-a-non-nullable-value-t/32485551)